# sikulix is there any way to run it independently in the background of a machine?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, sikuli, sikuli-x

I have been using sikulix for a while writing scripts for tests and general automation, as far as i have seen it is not possible to because silkulix needs keyboard input and a screen. Does anyone know if it is possible to a way to mock thses to enable to host it using amazon services.

Answer (score 0):

General advice for both Windows and Linux: You need to enable autologon and set appropriate resolution